# Inserting an Excel Column into SQL using an ADODB connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

'I am using an ADODB Connection to insert values from an Excel table in SQL.  So far it works.
'I would like to know how I can reference a column of cells in an Excel table in order to add it to my INSERT statement found below.
' Would it be this:

```vb
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A2:A20")

Server_Name = "MyServer" '
Database_Name = "dbMyDataBase" '

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"


' Compose the INSERT statement.
statement = "INSERT INTO [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_MyTable] VALUES (1,'90702', MyRange, '2014', 'ABC'), (2,'90703', MyRange, '2014', 'ABCD')"
' Execute the statement.
conn.Execute statement, , adCmdText

' Close the connection.
conn.Close
```

Comment: f1 is field 1 in Excel

Comment: So... what's the question? Look into what `For...Next` loop constructs can do for you.

Comment: The question is would like to know how I can reference a column of cells in an Excel table in order to add it to my INSERT statement found below.

Comment: You don't "reference a column of cells", you parameterize that SQL and *loop through row numbers* to get your parameter values at the row you're at. Hence, look into what `For...Next` loop constructs can do for you.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of this?  Also, is there another way to do this without a For...Next loop?